# Replace Random Characters in a Variable

Tags: regex, linux, variables, sed

I want to replace value of a variable (can contain a number, a character, a string of characters).

```
$ echo $VAR
http://some-random-string.watch.film.tv/nfvsere/watch/skrz1j8exe/chunks.m3u8?nimblesessionid=30931574352........
```

So far, I've tried this command, however it's not working, so I'm thinking some of these might need a regex.

```
$ echo $VAR | sed -e "s/\(http[^^]*\).*\(.watch\)/\1"mystring"\2/g"
$ echo $VAR | sed -e "s/\(https\?:\/\/\).*\(.watch\)/\1"mystring"\2/g"
$ echo $VAR | sed -e "s/\(http[s]\?:\/\/\).*\(.watch\)/\1"mystring"\2/g"
```

I'm aware that there are questions that answer similar queries, but they have not been of help.

Comment: The problem with using terms like `some-random-string` and `mystring` in a question is that as far as we know they can contain absolutely any characters which makes writing a regexp or a way to handle replacement text challenging. Can you be more specific on what it can/can't contain and show some truly representative examples in your question? Make sure to include the expected output as well as the sample input.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. In case it's not obvious, your selected answer will fail given various character in `mystring`, e.g. `&` or `|` or `\1` or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $VAR | sed 's|\(http[x]*://\)[^.]*\(.*\)|\1mystring\2|'
```

explanation

```
s|                 # substitute
\(http[x]*://\)    # save first part in arg1 (\1)
[^.]*              # all without '.'
\(.*\)             # save the rest in arg2 (\2)
|\1                # print arg1
mystring           # print your replacement
\2                 # print arg2
|
```

Answer (score 0):

In sed you have to escape any control characters like forward slash before matching:

```
echo $VAR | sed 's/http.\/\/.*\.watch\.film\.tv/http:\/\/mystring.watch.film.tv/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sed.  This task can be done in just shell:

```
$ var='http://some-random-string.watch.film.tv/nfvsere/watch/skrz1j8exe/chunks.m3u8?nimblesessionid=30931574352'
$ echo "${var%%//*}//mystring.watch${var#*.watch}"
http://mystring.watch.film.tv/nfvsere/watch/skrz1j8exe/chunks.m3u8?nimblesessionid=30931574352
```

How it works:

1. `${var%%//*}` returns the value of `$var` with the first `//` and everything after it removed.
2. `//mystring.watch` adds the string that we want.
3. `${var#*.watch}"` returns the value of `$var` with everything up to and including the first occurrence of `.watch` removed.

Because this approach does not require pipelines or subshells, it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

gnu sed

```
$ echo $VAR | sed -E 's/^(http:\/\/)\S+(\.watch\.film\.tv\/)/\1"mystring"\2/i'
```